# requestRouteToHost(int networkType, int hostAddress) is not working in 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-networking, connectivity, android-mms

**requestRouteToHost(int networkType, int hostAddress)**

This method was **deprecated** in API level 21. Deprecated in favor of the

**requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, NetworkCallback)**

**bindProcessToNetwork(Network)**
and **getSocketFactory()**

API. In **M**, and above, this method is unsupported and will throw UnsupportedOperationException if called. [Reference of Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Android official site dont have any implementation as a alternative of **requestRouteToHost(int networkType, int hostAddress)**

I google and found this

```
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        
                  ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        
                    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
      
                    //what Capability i have to add for 
                    **requestRouteToHost(int networkType, int hostAddress)** implementation.
                    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_MMS);
                    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
             
                    NetworkRequest networkRequest = builder.build();
                    connMgr.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        
                        @Override
                        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                            super.onAvailable(network);
                            //  sendNormalMms();
                            try {
                                int y = Integer.parseInt(apns.get(0).MMSPort);
                                HttpUtils.httpConnection(mContext, 4444L,
                                        apns.get(0).MMSCenterUrl, bytesToSend,
                                        HttpUtils.HTTP_POST_METHOD,
                                        !TextUtils.isEmpty(apns.get(0).MMSProxy),
                                        apns.get(0).MMSProxy, y);
        
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

**Issue:** Connectivity is not getting ready to send MMS
curser is not getting on `OnAvalabile();`

Is this the right to ready decive to send MMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Issue:**

Mobile data is trun off thats why state is not getting ready to send MMS.